# Callback of gundb.once is called with errormessage: Error: No ACK received yet

Tags: node.js, gun

I tried out gundb in node.js. Calling once after calling get two times results in an error. I did the following in the node console:

```
var Gun = require("gun/gun");
var gundb = Gun();
gundb.get('user').get('friends').put({name:"Joe"});
gundb.get('user').get('friends').once(function(data,key){ console.log(data);});
```

and I got the following error:

```
{ err: 'Error: No ACK received yet.', lack: true }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Timbow `require('gun/gun')` in NodeJS includes **only** GUN core, no storage adapters.

So after 9 seconds, the `put` timeouts with a warning/error that no ACK (acknowledgement) has been received that the data was saved to disk.

If you `require('gun/gun'); require('gun/lib/store');` you'll manually include the new NodeJS default storage engine - RAD (Radix storage engine).

Does this answer your question, or are you wanting to know something else?

Comment: Thanks, that solved the problem. Maybe I should have read the docs more carefully ;)